# require is not defined when I use D3.js as 'import * as d3 from d3' (Vue)

Tags: webpack, d3.js, frontend, vuejs3, babeljs

I'm currently trying to use d3 from an ongoing company project. The project is using Vue3 (made by vue-cli), and javascript (not Typescript..)

The project is made with Vue-Cli, and for some reasons I cannot migrate this project into Vite for a while.

So what I want for now is just make d3 available in this project, but when I use "import * as d3 from 'd3'",  ReferenceError occurred. Other libraries worked well when I use "import * as ( ) from ( )".

I assume that might be a webpack or babel issue, but I'm not used to setting those (and I didn't set up this project), so I have no idea for solving this problem.

**The Import Call**

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "core-js": "^3.8.3",
  "d3": "^7.8.5",
  "vue": "^3.2.13",
  ...
},

"devDependencies": {

    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0"
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
});
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
};
```

I want to make d3 available..